# Applying non-trivial functions to ordered subsets of data.table

Tags: r, data-structures, out-of-memory, data.table

#### Problem

I'm trying to use my newfound data.table powers (for good) to compute the frequency content of a bunch of data that looks like this:

```
|  Sample|  Channel|  Trial|     Voltage|Class  |  Subject|
|-------:|--------:|------:|-----------:|:------|--------:|
|       1|        1|      1|  -196.82253|1      |        1|
|       1|        2|      1|   488.15166|1      |        1|
|       1|        3|      1|  -311.92386|1      |        1|
|       1|        4|      1|  -297.06078|1      |        1|
|       1|        5|      1|  -244.95824|1      |        1|
|       1|        6|      1|  -265.96525|1      |        1|
|       1|        7|      1|  -258.93263|1      |        1|
|       1|        8|      1|  -224.07819|1      |        1|
|       1|        9|      1|   -87.06051|1      |        1|
|       1|       10|      1|  -183.72961|1      |        1|
```

There are about 57 million rows--every variable is an integer except Voltage. Sample is an index that goes from 1:350, and Channel goes from 1:118. There are 280 Trials.

#### sample data

Martín's example data is valid, I believe (the numbers of categorical variables are a non-issue with respect to the errors):

```
big.table <- data.table(Sample = 1:350, Channel = 1:118, Trial = letters,
             Voltage = rnorm(10e5, -150, 100), Class = LETTERS, Subject = 1:20)
```

#### process

The first thing I do is set the key to Sample, because I want anything I do to the individual data series to happen in a sane order:

```
setkey(big.table,Sample)
```

Then, I do some filtering on the Voltage signals to remove high frequencies. (The filtering function returns a vector of the same length as its second argument):

```
require(signal)
high.pass <- cheby1(cheb1ord(Wp = 0.14, Ws = 0.0156, Rp = 0.5, Rs = 10))
big.table[,Voltage:=filtfilt(high.pass,Voltage),by=Subject]
```

#### initial error

I'd like to see if that processed it properly (i.e. Subject by Subject, Trial by Trial, Channel by Channel, in Sample order), so I add a column containing the spectral content of the Voltage column:

```
get.spectrum <- function(x) {
    spec.obj <- spectrum(x,method="ar",plot=FALSE)
    outlist <- list()
    outlist$spec <- 20*log10(spec.obj$spec)
    outlist$freq <- spec.obj$freq
    return(outlist)
  }
big.table[,c("Spectrum","Frequency"):=get.spectrum(Voltage),by=Subject]

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 6.1 Gb
```

I think the issue is that `get.spectrum()` is trying to eat the whole column at once, considering that the whole table is only around 1.7GB. Is that so? What are my options?

### What have you tried?

#### Increasing the granularity of grouping

If I make a call to `get.spectrum` including all of the columns I want to group by, I get a more promising error:

```
big.table[,c("Spectrum","Frequency"):=get.spectrum(Voltage),
        by=c("Subject","Trial","Channel","Sample")]

Error in ar.yw.default(x, aic = aic, order.max = order.max, na.action = na.action,  : 
  'order.max' must be >= 1
```

That implies the `spectrum()` function I'm calling is getting data of the wrong shape.

#### Cutting points down, trying different 'where' conditions

Following Roland's advice, I cut the number of points to around 20 million and tried the below:

```
big.table[,"Spectrum":=get.spectrum(Voltage),
        by=c("Subject","Trial","Channel")]

Error in `[.data.table`(big.table, , `:=`("Spectrum", get.spectrum(Voltage)),  :
  All items in j=list(...) should be atomic vectors or lists. If you are trying something like
  j=list(.SD,newcol=mean(colA)) then use := by group instead (much quicker), or cbind or merge 
  afterwards.
```

My thinking was that I shouldn't group by Sample since I want to apply this function to each group of 350 Samples given by the above `by` vector.

Improving on that with some things gleaned from section 2.16 of the data.table FAQ, I added the SQL equivalent of an `ORDER BY`. I know that the Sample column needs to go from 1:350 for each input to the `spectrum()` function:

```
> big.table[Sample==c(1:350),c("Spectrum","Frequency"):=as.list(get.spectrum(Voltage)),
+             by=c("Subject","Trial","Channel")]
Error in ar.yw.default(x, aic = aic, order.max = order.max, na.action = na.action,  : 
  'order.max' must be >= 1
```

Again, I run into trouble with non-unique inputs.

Comment: Before you use this in a huge data.table, you should test with a subset of your data. Also, if you work with this much data in R and don't have at least 16 GB RAM, my advise would be to invest in some more memory. It's not that expensive nowadays.

Comment: You're right, of course; I cut out most of the subjects which brought me down to 23 million points at 618MB.

Comment: @TrevorAlexander It will be easier to help you if you would simulate some data.

Comment: I feel confident enough with data.table to do that now.

Comment: @TrevorAlexander i mean simulate some data that has similar characteristics to the one you are working, so we can try your code and answer the question.

Comment: @MartínBel I added an amateur answer that sort of explains what I was looking for with a couple of poor solutions. If you would like to add yours based on our discussion, I'd be happy to accept yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some [extended discussion with Martín Bel](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45423/discussion-between-trevor-alexander-and-martin-bel) who was patient enough to listen to me thrash, I was able to work out some of what was going wrong.

#### initial error

A major issue is that `spectrum()`, the function being called on each time-series component of the data.table, expects a 2D structure representing a multivariate time series (in this case, `channels x samples`). So this call

```
big.table[,c("Spectrum","Frequency"):=get.spectrum(Voltage),by=Subject]

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 6.1 Gb
```

is totally bad.

#### brute 'for'ce

Here is a slow way to do it using (mostly useless) parallelization. `get.spectrum()` is modified to return a simple vector, which was related to the third error on return types from `j`:

```
get.spectrum <- function(x) {
    spec.obj <- spectrum(x,method="ar",plot=FALSE)
    outlist <- list()
    outlist <- 20*log10(spec.obj$spec)
    # outlist$freq <- spec.obj$freq # don't return me
    return(outlist)
}

require(parallel)
require(foreach)
freq.bins <- 500
spectra <- foreach(s.ind = unique(big.table$Subject), .combine=rbind) %:% {
              foreach(t.ind = unique(big.table$Trial), .combine=rbind) %dopar% {
                
                cbind((sampling.rate * (seq_len(freq.bins)-1) / sampling.rate),
                  rep(c.ind,freq.bins),
                  rep(t.ind,freq.bins),
                  get.spectrum((subset(big.table, 
                   subset=(Subject==s.ind & 
                             Trial==t.ind),
                   select=Voltage))$Voltage),
                  rep(s.ind,freq.bins))
               
              }
            }
```

This gives the right result because each input to `get.spectrum()` is a subset where Subject and Trial are fixed, leaving Channel and Sample to vary. However, it is quite slow, and spends over 80% of the computational load in 1 of the 4 cores I have on this machine.

#### data.table approach

I went back to some toy cases that came up in the discussion, and tried this again:

```
spec.dt <- big.table[,get.spectrum(Voltage),by=c("Subject","Trial")]
```

This is close! It returns a data.table of almost the right structure.

```
> str(spec.dt)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  140000 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Subject: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Trial  : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ V1     : num  110.7 109 105.4 101.6 98.2 ...
```

However, the Channel variable is missing. Easily fixed:

```
> spec.dt <- erp.table[,get.spectrum(Voltage),by=c("Subject","Trial","Channel")]
> str(spec.dt)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  16520000 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Subject: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Trial  : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Channel: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ V1     : num  78.6 78.6 78.6 78.5 78.5 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Is this right? Well, it's easy to check if it's the right shape. We know that there are 500 frequency bins in the default `spectrum()` call, and I stated that the data had 118 channels.

```
> nrow(spec.dt)
[1] 16520000
> nrow(spec.dt)/500
[1] 33040
> nrow(spec.dt)/500/118
[1] 280
```

I didn't mention it in the original question, but there are indeed 280 trials.

#### remark

An apparent rule here is that in the `by` argument, you need to leave out the independent variable corresponding to the dependent data. If you don't, the other error appears.

```
> spectra.table <- big.table[,get.spectrum(Voltage),by=c("Sample","Subject","Channel")]
Error in ar.yw.default(x, aic = aic, order.max = order.max, na.action = na.action,  : 
  'order.max' must be >= 1
```

Here Voltage is a function of Sample (since sample is an index)--it is repeated over and over again for each Channel and each Subject.

I don't know exactly what the problem is here, though.

#### benchmarks

```
> system.time(spec.dt <- erp.table[,get.spectrum(Voltage),by=c("Subject","Trial","Channel")])
   user  system elapsed 
 86.669   3.452  87.414

system.time(
  spectra <- foreach(s.ind = unique(erp.table$Subject), .combine=rbind) %:% 
              foreach(t.ind = unique(erp.table$Trial), .combine=rbind) %dopar% {
                
                cbind((sampling.rate * (seq_len(freq.bins)-1) / sampling.rate),
                  rep(c.ind,freq.bins),
                  rep(t.ind,freq.bins),
                  get.spectrum((subset(erp.table, 
                   subset=(Subject==s.ind & 
                             Trial==t.ind),
                   select=Voltage))$Voltage),
                  rep(s.ind,freq.bins))
               
              })
   user  system elapsed 
114.259  17.937 131.873
```

The second benchmark is optimistic; I had run it a second time without cleaning up the environment or removing variables.

Comment: Never knew that data.table can accept a list returned from a function, this is amazing. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this can start to solve the problem:

```
I believe the error data.table gives is because get.spectrum returns a list with:
spec and freq.

Using this example dataset:
big.table <- data.table(Sample = 1:350, Channel = 1:118, Trial = letters,
                 Voltage = rnorm(10e5, -150, 100), Class = LETTERS, Subject = 1:20)

str(big.table)
setkey(big.table,Sample)

get.spectrum <- function(x) {
  spec.obj <- spectrum(x,method="ar",plot=FALSE)
  outlist <- list()
  outlist$spec <- 20*log10(spec.obj$spec)
  outlist$freq <- spec.obj$freq
  return(outlist)
}

VT <- get.spectrum(big.table$Voltage)
str(VT)

# Then you should decide which value you would like to inset in big.table
get.spectrum(big.table$Voltage)$spec
# or
get.spectrum(big.table$Voltage)$freq
```

This should work. You can also use `set()`

```
big.table[, Spectrum:= get.spectrum(Voltage)$spec, by=Subject]
big.table[, Frequency:= get.spectrum(Voltage)$freq, by=Subject]
```

**EDIT**
As mentioned in the comments, i've tried to provide an answer using set() but i don't see how to "group by" Subject: Here is what i've tried, not sure if it's the intended answer.

```
cols = c("spec", "freq")
for(inx in cols){
  set(big.table, i=NULL, j=j ,value = get.spectrum(big.table[["Voltage"]])[inx])
}
```

**EDIT2**
Two functions one for each colum. Using a different combination of group by variables.

```
spec_fun <- function(x) {
  spec.obj <- spectrum(x,method="ar",plot=FALSE)
  spec <- 20*log10(spec.obj$spec)
  spec
}

freq_fun <- function(x) {
  freq <- spectrum(x,method="ar",plot=FALSE)$freq
  freq
}

big.table[, Spectrum:= spec_fun(Voltage), by=c("Subject","Trial","Channel")]
big.table[, Frequency:= freq_fun(Voltage), by=c("Subject","Trial","Channel")]

# It gives some warnings(), probaby because of the made up data.
```

Comment: You beat me to an answer *and* a nice edit; I wanted to give a small random sampling of rows with one subject and one channel, but I got stuck trying to figure out how to do it with data.table. The `set()` method performs the calculation twice, right?

Comment: I've trying to come up with a set answer but it's not working right. I'm not sure if it can handle the by=variable. Perhaps an alternative is to write two functions: one for freq, the other for spec. Then use ```lapply(.SD, NEW_FUN)``` if you intend to do this for many columns. If it's just for two, i guess this is ok.

Comment: *Technically* I can compute `freq` outside as `(seq_len(500)-1) / 500` where 500 is the number of points returned, but it would be nice to understand how to add two columns at a time. I saw in some other question that `c("Spectrum","Frequency"):=` should work, but I didn't manage it.

Comment: How does `VT <- get.spectrum(big.table$Voltage)` know how to pass the voltages in order, separately by subject/channel/trial? Does `setkey()` guarantee that?

Comment: Testing with `dualchan.table <- data.table(Sample = 1:350, Channel = 1:2, Trial = 1,Voltage = rnorm(350*2), Class = 1, Subject = 1)` and a single-Channel table like it seems to suggest that some kind of `by` grouping is in order, but I'm unclear on how.

Comment: @TrevorAlexander run str(VT) and it will output a list. I'm not using VT at all, other than to show it's a list. To insert a column in a ```data.table``` you need to index the list, meaning access one column at a time.

Comment: @TrevorAlexander you only have one subject in dualchan.table. Is your dataset like this? I don't see how you can group by one subject then.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45423/discussion-between-trevor-alexander-and-martin-bel)